# Compare two lists and get the different items only in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

My object has 3 fields - Student, Term, Subject and Marks. I want to have a list of items whose marks are different for any subject.

eg:

```
 First list is 
             Alice, Term1, English,90
             Alice, Term1, Maths, 60
             Alice, Term1, Physics, 30

    Second list is 
             Alice, Term2, English, 95
             Alice, Term2,Maths, 60
             Alice, Term2, Physics, 20
```

In the final list I want to get the difference values only

Alice, English +5
Alice, Physics -10

How can i do this using Linq(c#)

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to do it, actually.  One mentioned using a custom comparer.  One used a dictionary, though thats not necessary.

```
// 1) use group by and only select groups with one item in them
var qqq = from r in one.Union(two)
          group r by new { r.Term, r.Mark } into g
          where g.Count() == 1
          select g.First();

// 2) work from a complete list and then remove stuff
var all   = one.Union(two).ToList();

// select only the records that have a count of one
var uniq = from a in all 
           where all.Count(y => y.Term == a.Term && y.Mark == a.Mark) == 1
           select a;

// -or- find all the duplicates and the remove them
var dupes = all.Where(x => all.Count(y => y.Term == x.Term && y.Mark == x.Mark) > 1).ToList();
var uniq  = all.Except(dupes).ToList();
```

There are far too many ways to go about this.

### **Edit**

Now that I've had a second to think, it seems there is an easy way to do this all in one step.  Not sure the entire requirements, but here it is:

```
var calcd = from t1 in one
            let t2 = two.FirstOrDefault(x => DataMatch(t1, x))
            where t2 != null
            select new {
                Name = t1.Name,
                Class = t1.Class,
                Change = t2.Mark - t1.Mark
            };

public static bool DataMatch(Data x, Data y)
{
    return x.Name == y.Name && x.Class == y.Class &&
           x.Term != y.Term && x.Mark  != y.Mark;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this may be your desired (but not tested unfortunately...):

```
        var result = secondList.Union(firstList)
            .GroupBy(m => Tuple.Create(m.Student, m.Subject))
            .ToDictionary(m => m.Key, n => n.OrderBy(m=>m.Term).Select(s => s.Marks).Aggregate((t1, t2) => t2 - t1))
            .Where(m=>m.Value != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var comparer = new SomeClassComparer(); /*must implement IEaualityComparer<SomeClass>*/
var list1 = new List<SomeClass>() { /*...*/ };
var list2 = new List<SomeClass>() { /*...*/};

var result = list1.Except(list2, comparer).Union(list2.Except(list1, comparer));
```